# how to easy to set the "indexView" on tableview right side when large data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

now i have a tableView and need show the indexView on right side.

yes i know have UITableViewDelegate to do this, but the problem is there are about 3000 records, i know if the server return the all records in one times, the index on the indexView are correct, i know this may no the good way to do this, but i have no other ideas, pleas help?

could you advise any suggestion?

when server paging return the data(100/times), and how to set the indexView correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You wants to add pagination on table view?

Comment: @VinayKumar no, i mean i need show the index on the tableview right side, like the address book right side index "ABCD...."